# Pulling a gitlab repository to the local repo

Tags: repository, gitlab, libgit2sharp

How do I pull some updates to local repository from Gitlab remote using libgit2sharp?
Gitlab repo uses no authentication - it is public (and should be).

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at any samples?  Or examples?  Or the unit tests with LibGit2Sharp?

Comment: I figured it out, actually. `Commands.Pull()` works, though remote should update, and then your local copy will update.